# RMI java doesn't create skeleton class

Tags: java, rmi

I wrote a remote service MyremoteImpl.java and used following command after compiled it.

```
rmic MyRemoteImpl
```

I learned that this method suppose to create stub class and a skeleton class but I can only see the stub class, why is that?

The other problem I faced after run rmiregistry I started the service but it gives following error, I doubt I get this error as I'm missing skeleton class?

```
 java.net.MalformedURLException: invalid URL String: Remote Hello
    at java.rmi.Naming.parseURL(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at RMIservice.MyRemoteImpl.main(MyRemoteImpl.java:22)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 6: Remote Hello
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.intParseURL(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

Please help me to solve this, Thanx in advance!!!

Comment: If I remember correctly, skeleton classes are no longer created. Your exception seems to point to an invalid URL. Can you post the URL you are using to connect?

Comment: Thanx a lot for your answer! finally I got rid of that exception... and to create skeleton class I found that rmic -v1.1 would work :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this. You don't need it. Skeleton classes haven't been required since 1998.

Answer (score 0):

From rmic 1.2 onwards, Java don't generate skeletion class any more. New JRMP protocol supported for RMI has got rid of the use of skeleton files.

> A skeleton for a remote object is a JRMP protocol server-side entity that has a method that dispatches calls to the actual remote object implementation.